A question about the f without fixed points conjugate to rotation
The question states:
if $f$ is a diffeomorphism $S^1\to S^1$ without any fixed point, and f is generated by a vector field, how to show that f is conjugate to rotation?
"$f$ is generated by a vector field" means there exists a vector field producing a global defined flow $\Phi$,$f=\Phi_t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
"conjugate" means there exist a homeomorphism $h$ so that $h^{-1}fh=R$ where $R$ is a rotation,i.e. $R\in SO(2)$.
I attempted to write $f(p)$ as $\mathrm{exp}_p(Vt)$ for each point p, it can be written specifically in local coordinates spanned by$\{\partial_{\theta}\}$ or written as $\{\partial_x,\partial_y\}$ when we regard the circle as the submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the rotaion can  be written specifically as weell. But I still don't konw how to use no fixed point to find "$h$",thanks.
